# Edit database entry created with Drupal 8 and Webform

Tags: webforms, drupal-8

I want to allow my users to edit data that has been entered using Webform in Drupal 8.

Can anyone point me to some examples of how this might be accomplished, please? Or post something here that shows how this can be accomplished.

I already have my data-entry form set up with Webform, but now want to retrieve this data for editing, and it makes sense to use the same form for my users, if possible.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Please post Drupal/Webform questions to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webform

Comment: Thanks, Jay, I figured that out, posted it over there, and then deleted the post because I was coming up with some  answers on my own.

Love Webform and thank you so much for creating it, and working so hard on your tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

CRUD operations are fully supported by the webform module.

You need to configure permissions (/admin/people/permissions#module-webform) and access rules (/admin/structure/webform/manage/contact/access) to allow users to update submissions.